# Testing a Conditional Statement

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, nunit

I want to test a method with no return, which only runs code if a passed in bool is set to true.

I'd like to test that when the bool is false, no code is called. I expect, this is maybe a case of refactoring to make my code more testable.

Code speaks a thousand words, so here's my method (constructor and dependencies left out for brevity):

```
...

public void Handle(Notification notification)
{
    if (notification.IsRestarting)
    {
        var installedVersion = _versionService.GetValue("Version");

        var packageVersion = "1.0.0";

        if (installedVersion.IsNullOrWhiteSpace())
        {
            _service.Initialise();
        }
    
        _versionService.SetValue("Version", packageVersion);
    }
}

...
```

I'm using `Moq` for mocking.

The `_versionService` actually sets the value in a SQL database table. This is a third-party service, though it is mockable.

So, if `isRestarting` is false, the method should do nothing. How do I test this, or make my code more testable?

Comment: are you using `Moq` for `_service` and `_versionService`?

Comment: looks like packageVersion should be a param to test...

Comment: There isn't enough context here. Typically you would be using a mocking library and you would be able to mock the dependency. That said, you haven't included those details in your quesiton.

Comment: you can check if the `versionService` changed in any way. However we can't know what that service is and how you can determine if `SetValue` was called on it for instance.

Comment: @Jonesopolis Yep, added this to the question also.

Comment: if the `versionService` is mockable, it is easy to fake it using `versionService.ShouldntBeCalled()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check that your services were never called.  Assuming that `_versionService` is a `Mock<ISomeVersionService>`.  Some rough code -

```
[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
    //call the method
    Handle(new Notification { IsRestarting = false });

    //verify nothing happened
    _versionService.Verify(x => x.GetValue(It.IsAny<string>(), Times.Never))

    //handle _service similarly
}
```